# Get regex to stop at a certain character, but include that character in match

Tags: php, regex

Right now, this regex matches something and stops at a slash ( / ), but I need it to stop at the slash and include the slash. Or in other words stop at whatever character is after the slash. But, I don't know what that charcter is.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Here is the regex:

```
   (?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\/]*
```

Comment: If you are trying to extract URLs from a block of text, I will bet you a nickel that there are existing tools that will do it for you in your language of choice, and existing questions here on StackOverflow that address exactly what it is you're trying to do.  A few minutes of searching may save you hours of writing, testing and debugging your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways :

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\/]*\/
```

or this :

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www).*?\/
```

**Edit:**

To stop at the lasts slash use this :

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\/]+(?:\S*?\/)*
```

Comment: Thank you. This stops at and includes the first slash. How can I stop at and include the last slash.

Comment: what do you mean ? give me an example

Comment: `http://www.google.com/` Right now it will match all of that, but not `http://www.google.com/dinosaurs/` It will stop at the first slash after .com

Comment: see my edit (but that will not match `http://www.google.com/dinosaurs/t-rex.php`)

Comment: I don't need it to match the t-rex.php part, just everything before it.

Comment: uh oh, now it only matches `http://www.google.com/dinosaurs/` I also need it to match `http://ask.com`,`www.go.com`, and `https://blackberry.com/`. So everything that may start with an http://, https://, www, and ends on the last slash.

Answer (score 0):

Add the slash as part of your regular expression:

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\/]*\/
                         ^^ add this
```

Comment: Thank you. But this stops and includes the first slash. How can I stop and include the last slash?